# Scala determine if global ExecutionContext finished all tasks

Tags: scala, executioncontext

I am writing some tests for a service that executes some non-io tasks asynchronously and uses callbacks. I need each test to wait until all callbacks are finished. Is it possible to determine that

```
scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

is done with all tasks?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a service like this:

```
class MyService {
  def asyncDouble(i: Int): Future[Int] = Future.successful {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    i * 2
  }
}
```

You can test it like this with ScalaTest:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures

class MyServiceSpec extends FunSuite with ScalaFutures {

  test("Should double the input") {
    val service = new MyService

    val future = service.asyncDouble(10)

    whenReady(future) { result =>
      assert(result == 20)
    }
  }
}
```

Or if you are making a Play! app and using `PlaySpec`, then you can use the `Helpers` which have an `await` function:

```
import org.scalatestplus.play.PlaySpec
import play.api.test.Helpers._

class MyServiceSpec extends PlaySpec {

  "Should double the input" in {
    val service = new MyService

    val future = service.asyncDouble(10)

    val result = await(future)
    result mustEqual 20
  }
}
```

Comment: that would work if I could actually get a reference to the futures I need to wait on. These are black box integration tests. I should have probably clarified that.

Comment: Does your service function not return a `Future`?  Or are you firing off async code in your service function and not waiting for it?

Comment: The service function it self returns true/false whether input is valid. Input may be  split into batches, processed, and eventually written to some destination. I need the tests to wait for all steps to complete, preferable without polling.

Comment: Hmm I think in this case, if the destination was some sort of DB, I would mockup the database and hand in that mocked up trait to your service.  That way you could examine the things that are being passed in, and now how many things to expect.

Comment: I was just hoping there is a easy, pretty way to do it. Ended up implementing my own execution context and using awaitTermination at the end of every test on the underlying Java executor service.